# Google Maps API v3 - change strokeWeight of polylines for different zoom levels

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have use Google Maps API v3 to create polylines representing trails on numerous maps. There are multiple polylines on each map. When zoomed out I would like the polylines to have a lighter strokeWeight, but heavier when zoomed in. I tried adding a zoom change listener and have it change a variable value for the strokeWeight, but it doesn't appear to work. I need Google to somehow redo the google.maps.Polyline({...}). Also, I need to do this globally, as I said, I have many polylines on each map.

I did do research on this, as it must be a common issue, but I didn't find anything on this topic.

Does anyone have an approach for this?

```
var polyWidth = 8;
var eiffellouvrePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: eiffellouvre,
    strokeColor: '#aa0022',
    strokeOpacity: .8,
    strokeWeight: polyWidth
});

eiffellouvrePath.setMap(map);
/************************************************/
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    if (zoom <= 10) {
        polyWidth = 3;
    } else {
        polyWidth = 8;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to actually update the `Polyline`'s width here, so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  var zoom = map.getZoom();
  if (zoom <= 10) {
    eifellouvrePath.setOptions({strokeWeight: 3});
  } else {
    eifellouvrePath.setOptions({strokeWeight: 8});
  }
});
```

If you need to do this globally, I would suggest storing your polylines and running through each one to update its `strokeWeight`.

**EDIT**

You've mentioned you want to create and apply this stroke width change to multiple `Polyline`s.

Here's one way to do that.

```
var paths = [];
// Fill paths with the Arrays of LatLngs describing the Polyline path.

var polylines = [];
for (var i = 0; paths[i]; ++i) {
  // Create a new function scope.
  function(i) {
    var poly;
    poly = polylines[i] = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: paths[i],
      strokeColor: '#aa0022',
      strokeOpacity: .8,
      strokeWeight: (map.getZoom() <= 10) ? 3 : 8
    });
    poly.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      var zoom = map.getZoom();
      if (zoom <= 10) {
        poly.setOptions({strokeWeight: 3});
      } else {
        poly.setOptions({strokeWeight: 8});
      }
    });
  }(i);
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach and it did not work. And yes, I noticed the spelling change for the path in your reply and fixed that in my code - still not working.

Comment: Brilliant! I got it to work this time. I may have had some syntax glitch before. Now I need to contemplate how to apply it to literally hundreds of polylines that have already been created...I need to think about this a bit so that it loads for each file. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried adding an extra code snippet at the end to account for multiple polylines. Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Just fyi, the function(i) part gives a javascript error and when zooming in / out, only the last poly changes strokeWeight, not all. Looks like the event listener only listens to the last poly, despite it being called in inside the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the strokeWeight option of the polyline (`eiffellouvrePath`).

```
polyWidth = 3;
eiffellouvrePath.setOptions({
  strokeWeight: polyWidth
});
```

[Proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/g8zn4zb2/),

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var eiffellouvre = [new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.2)
  ]
  var polyWidth = 8;
  var eiffellouvrePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: eiffellouvre,
    strokeColor: '#aa0022',
    strokeOpacity: .8,
    strokeWeight: polyWidth
  });

  eiffellouvrePath.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    if (zoom <= 10) {
      polyWidth = 3;
      eiffellouvrePath.setOptions({
        strokeWeight: polyWidth
      });
    } else {
      polyWidth = 8;
      eiffellouvrePath.setOptions({
        strokeWeight: polyWidth
      });
    }
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = polyWidth;
  });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```