# undesired polyline rendering while zooming in and out google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

[rendering reflected image of the polyline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcVcm.jpg)

I have an application to draw a polyline on latitude and longitude values which are fetched dynamically. I'm able to form the polyline perfectly but I see a reflected polyline forming somewhere around the map as I extend the polyline asynchronously which is undesirable (i get this issue even if I don't change the zoom of the map). please help me avoid that reflection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3 - change strokeWeight of polylines for different zoom levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721031/google-maps-api-v3-change-strokeweight-of-polylines-for-different-zoom-levels)

Comment: actually, im facing the issue even if I don't perform zooming. does google maps apiv3 have a problem with rendering? I have searched to avoid this but cant find a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Polygon artefacts showing on zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265609/google-maps-api-polygon-artefacts-showing-on-zoom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a Chrome browser issue.

The corresponding bug in the public issue tracker is

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38211242

Feel free to star the bug to add your vote and subscribe to further updates.

**UPDATE**

As stated in Google issue tracker, the issue was fixed in Chrome 60. The corresponding bug was marked as Fixed on August 9, 2017.

Answer (score 0):

This was a chrome browser issue that has now been fixed in chrome Version 60.0.3112.90.

Make sure that you have your chrome version up to date by clicking the three dots on the top right of chrome Help > About Google Chrome

[image: Navigateion to About Google Chrome]

This should show you what version of chrome you are running.

Comment: improve this a litte better, it looks like a comment instead of an answer